# Custom table cannot be added to the selected site due to license limitations in Kentico 9

Tags: kentico

I am getting this error when creating custom table with Kentico 9 CMS.
*Custom table cannot be added to the selected site due to license limitations.* I am using localhost (free license ) for development.
Anyone can suggest?
Thank you,
Vijay

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade you localhost license to a base or above in order for you to get past the free license limitation of 1 custom table